# Terminal-like WordPress Login

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress

Does someone know if there is already a library that will allow a terminal-like emulation, so that the admin can enter his credentials in a two-step way on the wp-admin site?

First he should be able to enter his username, hit enter and then enter his password. Based on the validity of the input, a message should be visible and a redirect should occur.

In this regard I am aware of [certain jQuery libraries](http://terminal.jcubic.pl) wich emulate the particular terminal style, but it did not came to my knowledge that there is some working code, which would accomplish my need wich I have mentioned above. Maybe I am also too unexperienced to notice that a plugin has the desired abilities, or maybe there is a very different way of accomplishing my desire and someone can help me out.

In any way I thank you for pointing me into the right direction.

#### Additional Information

My aim is *only* to build a login page - not the whole wordpress administration after the login process. This would be grotesque. A very nice example of how this login screen could function and behave can be found in [this demo](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/rpc-demo.html).

Answer (score 0):

actually if you need just terminal like login (so not the administration) it can be done quite easily

1. you need to make some black page with green text - you can rewrite the standard wp-login form using login_init action or you can e.g. make a new page called e.g. 'login' and then make  page-login.php in your template folder
2. you will put there a standard login form, something like

   ```
   <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="" method="post">
   <p id="user">
       <label for="user_login">Username<br />
       <textarea type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" cols="80" tabindex="10" ></textarea></label>
   </p>
   <p id="password">
       <label for="user_pass">Password<br />
       <textarea type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" cols="80" tabindex="20" ></textarea></label>
   </p>
   <p id="submit">
       <button name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button-primary" tabindex="100" >Login</button>
   </p>
   ```

   I just use textareas instead of inputs, as in terminal you can put more rows of text and button without type=submit, so the form will not be fired when clicked enter
3. You will hide all fields except #user using either CSS or javascript (javascript hidding is better for accesibility).
4. You will style label to green text and your text area to black background, no borders, green text.
5. if you want to to test, if user exist, before testing the password, as it is at some terminals (i do not recommends, it downgrade the security), you can then make test if not password  was in $_POST and check username only with http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/username_exists function when user clicked enter (better would be some asynchronous way using e.g. ajax).
6. when previous check is ok (user exist), you will make first textarea read-only and show only #password.
7. after clicking enter, you will check http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/user_pass_ok and if OK, you will redirect him to /wp-admin (you can simply send the credintials using post to wp_login.php). If not, you will show again the form (e.g. with prefilled user and with some $counter set to ++, and when $counter >= 3 you will send him to homepage.

Comment: You should use `input` for those fields, not `textarea`. Also `textarea` doesn't require or allow a `type` attribute. Edit: I'd also definitely remove the unnecessary `tabindex` attributes and also use a proper `input[type=submit]` for the submit button.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I have added some additional information - unfortunately it is not that easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can write php script that use XML-RPC to test if login password is right. All wordpress methods have username and password so you can pick any method like [wp.getOptions](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.getPosts) (It's safe because it don't change anything but you need to be authenitcated) which will return error 403 when you type wrong password, if the user/pass is right
Here is php code:

```
<?php
```

```
function post($url, $data) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    return curl_exec($ch);
}

function authenticate($user, $password) {
    $request = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <methodCall>
      <methodName>wp.getOptions</methodName>
      <params>
        <param>
          <value><int>0</int></value>
        </param>
        <param>
          <value><string>' . $user . '</string></value>
        </param>
        <param>
          <value><string>' . $password . '</string></value>
        </param>
      </params>
    </methodCall>';
    $url = 'http://www.domektkaczki.pl/xmlrpc.php';
    $regex = '/<name>faultCode<\/name>.*<value><int>403<\/int><\/value>/s';
    return !preg_match($regex, post($url, $request));
}
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
if (isset($_GET['user']) && isset($_GET['passwd'])) {
    echo authenticate($_GET['user'], $_GET['passwd']) ? 'true' : 'false';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

then in javascript you just call that script in terminal

```
$('body').terminal($.noop, {
    login: function(user, passwd, callback) {
        $.getJSON('auth.php', {user:user, passwd:passwd}, function(response) {
            if (response) {
                // the page redirected_page.php need to be password protected
                // because users will be able to see the code and open that page directly
                // you can use sessions to save value if user put right credentials
                // in auth.php and in redirected_page.php you can check
                // if that value is set
                window.location = 'redirected_page.php';
            } else {
                callback(null);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

If you will want to implement more wordpress commands you can use [xmlrpc library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpxmlrpc/), here is code [how to create a client](http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/doc-2/ch11.html). If you will want to have commands in javascript your login should return a token that can be used in javascript.

EDIT: if you want to login to admin interface and be logged (from terminal) then you can check wp-login, open developer tools, check preserve logs in network tab and see what request is send to the server. Then you can do the same request using AJAX in login function instead of php script I've written. You will need to check what response is send when you type wrong password and want when it's correct and use the same location and callback(null) as in JS code.